# Cannot render MaterialButton with android.material:1.1.x

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android

Whenever I use MaterialButton, I get the following exception in the xml preview:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

I have upgraded to android studio 3.4 and to com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05

Version 1.0.0 works but any 1.1.x doesn't.

Is this a problem with the IDE or the library?

-

For reference, the full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException@d8dc5d1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor893.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.pulseAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1490)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.pulseFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1163)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1146)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1046)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
    at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT** This happens only when the button style is not set OR the defaulted:

@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button

Setting as unelevated style works for example, so as a work around I'm using the tools namespace to show unelevated button style.

**Edit 2** the app theme parent is already correctly set as Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. This is an IDE issue as it is running well on my emulator and device. I have also done a clear cache & invalidate, clean build, rebuild... (the standard things we do when faced with weird IDE problems)

**Edit 3** Still no luck with the latest A.S. 3.4.1!

Comment: did you set your app theme to extend from Theme.MaterialComponent or its subclass?

Comment: This issue persists in alpha06 as well, and in Studio 3.5beta1

Answer (score 22):

**Update3**: This is finally fixed in [Studio 3.5beta2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/android-studio-35-beta-2-available.html)! We did it guys!

<s>**Update2**: I've filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132562197. Please star for visibility.</s>

<s>**Update**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55947981/3460025) is a cleaner workaround since we don't have to litter `tools:style` throughout our xml layouts.</s> This has stopped working for me for no apparent reason, I've had to revert to my original workaround described below.

---

Here's a workaround till we get an actual fix, based on Gautham's discovery:

Add this style to your `styles.xml`:

```
<!--  For the sake of xml preview not breaking  -->
    <style name="UnelevatedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    </style>
```

Add it to your `Button`s like so:

```
<Button
        ...
        tools:style="@style/UnelevatedButton"
        style="@style/ActualButtonStyle"
        />
```

Note that the ordering of the two is important, the `tools` line needs to come first.

You can update your `UnelevatedButton` to match your `ActualButtonStyle` for the sake of having previews consistent with your actual runtime buttons.

Comment: This worked for me! Issue seems to be elevation properties.

Comment: Also fixed 3.5 Beta3 :)

Comment: This won't work if you reformat your code inside the xml file. This answer needs to be edited and give more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Seems to fail again in beta 4

Comment: I am Facing the same issue on A.S. 3.4.2, It has been driving me crazy for a few days, Currently downloading A.S. 3.6 Canary 3. Hope the issue is resolved there. Will give a feedback when I'm done testing it

Answer (score 4):

I'm attempting to reproduce this issue currently, but I need more information. My current hypothesis is that it's related to button elevation (based on the animation calls in the stacktrace), which is also why unelevated button works as expected.

Could you please file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=439535&template=1121918 with the component name and description, as well as the information requested there?

Comment: I'll do that when I get back from my vacation I guess, and will update this topic when I get further info. For now I'm just using tools namespace to set style as unelevated

Comment: Can confirm, the unelevated button works for me as well.

Comment: I've made a report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132562197

Answer (score 4):

[amitav13's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880655/599570) has one major problem, when you reformat the code the default rules will rearrange all the attributes and then everything breaks again.

Instead, until this is fixed, my proposal is to create a separate application theme for using in preview windows, in this example this Theme is called **AppTheme.PreviewFix**.
Simply select this theme in Preview / Design panes.

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <attr name="buttonStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PreviewFix" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Button.PreviewFix</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button.PreviewFix" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"/>
</resources>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="?buttonStyle"
        ...
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

Comment: Cool, how if I want to customize my `Theme.Button`?

Answer (score 2):

Set your application theme from AppCompat to MaterialComponents such as below:

Use below style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

instead of

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I have the same problem and the theme has nothing to do with this (I already have `MaterialComponents` one)

Comment: i updated my android studio from 3.3.2 to 3.4 and after creating new project, i got the same problem when i take the material button with the style "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" and when i update my theme it run successfully

Comment: This was already done, I added "edit 2" in the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've downloaded another version of Android Studio.

It's Working Fine on A.S. 3.6 Canary 3... 
I'm Using API 29, and material_version = '1.1.0-alpha08'

Download it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html)

The last working version for my earlier Android Studio was material_version = '1.0.0'.

But it didn't have some of the new material component features, so Instead of rolling back, I decided to Update Android Studio.

Do what best suits your needs.

Cheers.