# Material Floating Action Button causing error and crashing xml

Tags: android, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I migrated to `androidx` and my dependencies are:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

I used `FloatingActionButton` :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_32dp"/>
```

But when I put `FloatingActionButton`, XML crashes(Render Problem). Even when I use the following :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

However, this error occurs only in XML and does not affect the execution of the program , and it does not show `design mode` for me.
The problem with `invalidate Cache and Restart` is that it temporarily resolves the issue, but it happens again.

The Render Problem is:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@7e11486d   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java:-1)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)   at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.startWithoutPulsing(ValueAnimator.java:1081)   at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1142)   at android.animation.AnimatorSet.startAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1227)   at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:729)   at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:684)   at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)   at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)   at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)   at android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged(ImageView.java:1294)   at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.drawableStateChanged   ... (FloatingActionButton.java:805)   at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)   at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)

Comment: make sure you apptheme is extending from `Theme.MaterialComponent` or its child

Comment: Most probably there is a problem with the `@drawable/ic_add_32dp` remove it and test once..

Comment: i tested all. didnt work

Comment: Maybe your migration to AndroidX is not properly done

Comment: Same problem here, with MaterialComponent theming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has been fixed in `Studio 3.5beta2!`
This issue seems to be elevation properties

For more information see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880655/4254527