# Android Studio preview doesn't show when a floating action button is in the layout

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

Exactly as the title suggests when I have a floating action button anywhere in my layout in any xml file the preview stops working, I can literally comment it out and it will instantly redraw perfectly. any ideas?

I have tried resetting multiple times syncing, invalidating caches etc.
When i reset the view is rendered fine but only for pages open any i open after will not render and navigating back to the previously rendered layout breaks it

The only thing I can think of is I use clans floating action button in my project, but it's the Google one that breaks my preview.

**EDIT** I've removed clans cleaned project invalidated caches restarted and still the issue persists

also if i change FloatingActionButton to ExtendedFloatingActionButton the preview draws fine, looking into those two it seems they extend completely different classes

Also using AndroidX

here is an example of an xml that will not render

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".settings.PdfSettingsActivity">

<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_16dp"
  android:elevation="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_4dp"
  android:id="@+id/pdf_renderer"/>




<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if i comment out the floating action button the view immediately renders

com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

> Android Studio 3.4.1 Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1,
>   2019 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>   VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.14.3

**EDIT**

Just playing around with it now and I manage to make it throw an an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@54291cbb
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor971.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime(ValueAnimator.java:1339)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1471)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.pulseAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1490)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.pulseFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1163)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1146)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1046)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100(AnimationHandler.java:37)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer_Delegate.doFrame(Choreographer_Delegate.java:66)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:563)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//Room dependencies
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
//GSON
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
//UI design
implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha06'
implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.VRGsoftUA:ParallaxView:1.0'
//Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
//Edit image
implementation 'com.yashoid:instacropper:1.0.6'
// FloatingActionButton
implementation 'com.github.martipello:FloatingActionButton:v2.0'
//Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0-alpha05"
// For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0-alpha05"
//material components
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-beta02'
//tests
testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180130'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your layout xml?

Comment: You can get some help with this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24523238/5773044

Comment: try to refresh your layout

Comment: @WilsonSim yes i can but i can assure you it wouldnt make a slight of difference i can make an empty xml, add any layout group, linear, constraint etc everything will be fine but the moment i add a floating action button the preview stops working, i can also add an entire layout with a floating action button, the layout wont render, if i remove the action button the layout preview redraws and is fine, and then adding the action button back the preview stays the same and will not update anymore

Comment: @AnupamBose thanks that can sometimes be an issue but not in this case, as already mentioned the preview is fine until i add the ation button

Comment: You probably saw the other answers there too, but sometimes you need to update your base style. In particular, if you have attributes in styles such as MaterialComponents, you require a preview with that style as well

Comment: Perhaps also verify that your appcompat versions are consistent

Comment: Do you have the right dependency for `Floating action button`? If you are using androidx, make sure the others library are androidx as well.

Comment: @AllanW i think this is the most likely but my base is currently Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge

Comment: @WilsonSim dependencies is a good shout will lokk at that now

Comment: @WilsonSim dependencies look fine, updated to alpha07 but no joy

Comment: YAY updated all dependencies invalidated cache and restarted android studio and the preview now displays

Comment: take that back it just worked for the layout it opened on start up

Comment: why has this been down voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Android Studio which should be fixed in [3.5 beta 2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/05/android-studio-35-beta-2-available.html) (as well as the [latest beta](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) I imagine). More specifically, this seems to have been [Issue#129926965](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129926965).

Credit: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880655/8643328)

Answer (score 1):

When comparing to the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/)... you probably have to use attribute 
`srcCompat` instead:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/share"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
   android:layout_margin="16dp"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"/>
```

While this part of the `build.gradle` appears confusing / redundant:

```
implementation "com.github.martipello:FloatingActionButton:v2.0"
```

Comment: thats a different floating action button library which i thought might be causing a conflict

Comment: thanks for the idea of using app:srcCompat but it didnt work (i actually think thats geared towards having drawable vectors)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you are using AndroidX. Since you can't use support libraries with AndroidX remove all the support libraries in your `build.gradle` files and add this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

To your `app/build.gradle` file.

**EDIT:**

If that didn't work, check for

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

in your `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: Same issue...? Did you try reverting back before getting that error? (You said you were messing around)

Comment: na, its been happening for months cant remember it ever working on my mac tbh

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle files?

Comment: @martinseal1987 please post the build.gradle files so we can help you.

Comment: added gradle dependencies

Comment: and i have both the android. lines in my properties file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing with the elevation of the button?

```
android:elevation
```

or

```
app:elevation
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug/issue in Android Studio 3.4.x https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132316448 You just have to wait for Android Studio 3.5. But if you also use the Beta versions then this issue seems to be rectified in beta 2 and above but not confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Try to write these lines manually in the Code section rather than in the design section.
It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I guess your cast in Activity or Fragment is written wrong.

Check you imported correct `FloatingActionButton` class. And it is correspond with your View in xml.

For example,

```
FloatingButton btnFab = (FloatingButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_fab) // Not FloatingActionButton
```

in your xml.

```
<!-- Not FloatingButton -->
<com.example.FloatingActionButton 
     android:id="@+id/btn_fab"
     android:layout_width = "45dp"
     android:layout_height = "45dp"
     />
```

Check if the class names are matched.

Comment: `com.example`?!

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException That's just an example package name which is not real.

Comment: A FloatingActionButton is a REAL thing. Just look at the OP's XML.

Comment: Besides, this doesn't address the problem. The OP hasn't even attached Java source code.

Comment: It can be customised.

Comment: What? Sorry I don't follow

Comment: It's just an example. And I am just saying he may need to check if he is using the same button in `java` and `xml`. And you can make custom view calls `FloatingActionButton` as well. So, I just put `com.example` in the beginning. It doesn't matter. And It's not important thing in this answer.